# Recursive function on list of dictionaries print results but returns none

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I wrote a code in order to calculate sentiment of values in a dictionary whose items came from a semantic labeling parser. The dictionaries items are nested in multiple lists I wrote this recursive code (some words are written in portuguese)

```
def walk(lst):
    sentimentos=[]
    new_sentiment={}
    #saida={}
    for ele in lst:
        if type(ele) is list:
            walk(ele)
        else:
            if isinstance(ele,dict):
                for k, v in ele.items():
                    sentimentos.append(calcula_sentimento(str(ele.values())))
                    print(sentimentos)
                    flat_sentimentos = [item for sublist in sentimentos for item in sublist] 
                    new_sentiment = {i: [j,k] for i, j, k in zip(ele.keys(), ele.values(), flat_sentimentos) }
                print(new_sentiment)
                return new_sentiment
```

As this function is executed output is somewhat unstable, but in general the output is None. Data is like this:

```
[[{'A0': 'Up to 140 asylum seekers', 'V': 'overpowered', 'A1': 
'security guards', 'AM-LOC': 'at the tunnel s entrance', 'AM-TMP': 'as 
trains passed by dangerously close'}, {'A0': 'Up to 140 asylum 
seekers', 'V': 'swarmed on', 'A1': 'to the tracks', 'AM-TMP': 'as 
trains passed by dangerously close'}, {'A1': 'trains', 'V': 'passed', 
'A2': 'by dangerously close'}]]
```

Expeced output is lite this:

```
[{'A0': ['Up to 140 asylum seekers', 0.34], 'V': 
['overpowered',-0.034], ...}
```

Code of calcula_sentimentos function adapted from git hub here:

```
def calcula_sentimento(doc):
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(doc)
stokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
taggedlist=[]
for stoken in stokens:        
     taggedlist.append(nltk.pos_tag(stoken))
wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()

score_list=[]
for idx,taggedsent in enumerate(taggedlist):
    score_list.append([])
    for idx2,t in enumerate(taggedsent):
        newtag=''
        lemmatized=wnl.lemmatize(t[0])
        if t[1].startswith('NN'):
            newtag='n'
        elif t[1].startswith('JJ'):
            newtag='a'
        elif t[1].startswith('V'):
            newtag='v'
        elif t[1].startswith('R'):
            newtag='r'
        else:
            newtag=''       
        if(newtag!=''):    
            synsets = list(swn.senti_synsets(lemmatized, newtag))

            score=0
            if(len(synsets)>0):
                for syn in synsets:
                    score+=syn.pos_score()-syn.neg_score()
                score_list[idx].append(score/len(synsets))

#print(score_list)
sentence_sentiment=[]
for score_sent in score_list:
    try:
        sentence_sentiment.append(sum([word_score for word_score in score_sent])/len(score_sent))
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        pass  #print("Escore do sentimento para:"+doc[1])
return sentence_sentiment
```

Why it is erratic and issuing not a complete output and returning none?

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you are trying to parse/restructure/filter ?

Comment: you need to return the result from `walk` call too i.e `return walk(ele)` in your `if`

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thank you for your comments. This is code is supposed to calculate a sentment score for each sentence block (subject, predicate and/or complements). These block are the output of a Semantic Labeling Parser. Input are fragments of news papers articles, and the output is the sentiment score for these fragments. Ok?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Thank you for your comments. Excuse me, but you mean in the body of `if isinstance(ele,dict):` ?

Comment: I executed the same function manually, and I got the correct output. 
    [{'A0': ['Up to 140 asylum seekers', -0.058], 'V': ['overpowered', -0.125], 
    'A1': ['security guards', 0.021], 'AM-LOC': ['at the tunnel s entrance', 0.0], 
    'AM-TMP': ['as trains passed by dangerously close', -0.010]},{'A0': ['Up to 
    140 asylum seekers', -0.058], 'V': ['swarmed on', 0.0], 'A1': ['to the tracks', 
    -0.022], 'AM-TMP': ['as trains passed by dangerously close', -0.010]},
    {'A1': ['trains', 0.0], 'V': ['passed', -0.015], 'A2': ['by dangerously close', 
    -0.012]}]

Comment: Difficult to reproduce without knowing, what `calcula_sentimento()` exactly returns. The fedora link was unresponsive - the reason, why SO asks users not to paste code on external sites.

Comment: @Piinthesky Thank you I will add function calcula_sentiment in a new edit. It returns average sentiment scores for each phrase chunks.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes I got the expected list of numbers for isolated sentences, It did not work so well for longer texts (800 words) Your inputs are raw sentences, or chunked sentences? At first I submit sentences parsed by Collobert's SENNA, semantic labeling parser, because I would like to know how subjects, verbs and objects (direct or indirect) would scored.

Comment: Oh, you are getting the output because you printed it, but you are not returning it because you don't have a return statement, as mentioned in the second comment. You tricked yourself with your debug prints. Change your debug prints to say print ("debug new_sentiment=", new_sentiment). Change your final print to say print ("function returned: ", walk(data))  This will make it more apparent why it is actually happening. If you have a debugger, break on the one return you have, look at the call stack, go to the previous call to walk. Note that you don't have a return statement there.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thank you! I will finish some work and go back to test it in a debugger.